# how to show multiple photo twitter status using php

Tags: php, twitter

i need to display/show photo with twitter api, but i have only get 1 photo

```
$results = $toa->get('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/show.json?id=xxxxxxxxxxxx' );



if (isset($results->entities->media)) {
foreach ($results->entities->media as $media) {
$media_url = $media->media_url; // Or $media->media_url_https for the SSL version.
}
}

echo $media_url;
```

this code get only 1 photo ,how to get pulling multiple image (max 4) on 1 twitter status ?

thank

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're overwriting the `$media_url` variable on each loop. You would want to loop through the `$results->entities->media` variable when displaying the images like this:

```
foreach ($results->entities->media as $media) {
    echo '<img src="'.$media->media_url.'"/>';
}
```

Comment: this still display one photo, not more, my status have 2 photo, any more idea?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know too much about the Twitter API however you are only getting one photo at the end because you are doing this.

Inside the loop you keep updating `$media_url` to `$media->media_url`. Then outside the loop you echo `$media_url` only *once*.

All you are doing is changing that one variable over and over, you need to have your echo statement inside the loop.

```
if (isset($results->entities->media)) {
    foreach ($results->entities->media as $media) {
        $media_url = $media->media_url;
        echo $media_url;
    }
}
```

Like I said I don't have too much knowledge of the Twitter API but providing your loop is working to get one of the images then moving the echo statement inside the loop should help.

Comment: this still display one photo, not more, my status have 2 photo

Comment: Are you sure your loop is happening twice? Does the loop print out the same image twice, or do you only get the image once? If you only have the one image you might be making the wrong API call.

Comment: i display results with print_r ($results) , result with json , api have call 2 image url